# How to get row value of HTML table using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the value of all rows that the button for the row has not been clicked on.

For example, when I click on the button on the first row, I want to retrieve the values of all other rows that have NOT been clicked on yet.

I would like to take the data from the rows that have not been clicked on and persist them to a JSON string.

```
<table id="all_departments">
 <thead>
          <th><button>click</button></th>                                   
          <th>Departments</th>
          <th>Creation Date</th>
          <th>Name</th>
 </thead>
<tbody class="bl">
       <tr>
            <td><button>click</button></td>
            <td>Management</td>
            <td>2-3-2016</td>
            <td>client x</td>
      </tr>

       <tr>
            <td><button>click</button></td>
            <td>Sales</td>
            <td>25-6-2019</td>
            <td>client y</td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Use an event listener on all the buttons. Then loop over all the rows, and check if the current row contains `event.target`. If not, add its value to the result.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, then you need `each()` all `tr`, except for the one where the `button` is, and put the text from `td` into the array:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
  const result = [];
  $(this).closest('table')
    .find('tr')
    .not( $(this).closest('tr') )
    .each( function(index) {
      if( !result[index] ) {
        result[index] = [];
      }
      $(this).find('th, td')
        .not(':first-child')
        .each( function() {
          result[index].push( $(this).text() );
        } )
    } );
  console.log( JSON.stringify(result, null, 2) );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><button>click</button></th>                                   
      <th>Departments</th>
      <th>Creation Date</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="bl">
    <tr>
      <td><button>click</button></td>
      <td>Management</td>
      <td>2-3-2016</td>
      <td>client x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button>click</button></td>
      <td>Sales</td>
      <td>25-6-2019</td>
      <td>client y</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```